# Raise event in specified time

Tags: c#, .net, timer, schedule

Can somebody give me a code, how to raise event when specified time is passed.

For example i have this times:

```
08:00 12:00 20:30 23:00
```

How can i subscribe to event which raising in these times?

Comment: How often do you want to check is current time == specified time?

Comment: You might want to use Windows Scheduled Tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following approach:

```
DateTime target = ...
int interval = (int)(target - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: I think you mean `int interval = (int)(target - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;` (you don't want just the msec fraction, ignoring secends and minutes)

Answer (score 0):

The method I used for an application was to make a timer that fires every few minutes. When it gets closer to the target time (e.g. current time + interval > target time), the interval becomes smaller.

For that particular application, exact precision wasn't that important, so I didn't let the interval get smaller than 500 ms.

Finally, when you think you're close enough, you do the task you need to at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).
It can run whatever you need in specified times, one of which is the firing of an event.

Answer (score 0):

use a System.Timers.Timer

Details on this can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

when the event goes off, raise the event AND reprogram the timer to go off again for your next event.